# JavaFX, Changing Pie Chart slices' name cause IllegalStateException

Tags: java, javafx

I am now work one JavaFX and now I create PieChart
I saw in tutorial "http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/pie-chart.htm#CIHFDADD"
that the pie chart label might be useful, thus I let it show the name and data value
as this

```
private String[] caption = {dataInp.getConstantValue(15, 8)+"\n"+(int)(percent[0]*100)+"%"
        , dataInp.getConstantValue(16, 8)+"\n"+(int)(percent[1]*100)+"%"
        , dataInp.getConstantValue(17, 8)+"\n"+(int)(percent[2]*100)+"%"
        , dataInp.getConstantValue(18, 8)+"\n"+(int)(percent[3]*100)+"%"};
pieChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new PieChart.Data(caption[0], percent[0]),
            new PieChart.Data(caption[1], percent[1]),
            new PieChart.Data(caption[2], percent[2]),
            new PieChart.Data(caption[3], percent[3]));
chart = new PieChart(pieChartData);
```

the result is perfectly fine as the initial
the next step is make it dynamic following the data user select by

```
public void setSlice(double percent, int index){
        pieChartData.get(index).setPieValue(percent);
        pieChartData.get(index).setName(caption[index]+"\n"+(int)(percent*100)+"%");
    }
```

and the line `pieChartData.get(index).setName(caption[index]+"\n"+(int)(percent*100)+"%");` cause

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread;
>   currentThread = AWT-EventQueue-0

Is there anyway to change the slice name? or make the result similar to what I describe above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most probable reason that can be seen from the `Exception` is that the method `setSlice()` is called from a thread other than `JavaFX Application Thread`.

There are many ways to resolve this issue:

1. This is the easiest one, call the method from the `JavaFX Application thread`
2. You can call the method from the Application Thread, or cover the method body inside [Platform.runLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-)

You can do something like:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
     setSlice(10, 3);
});
```

or,

```
public void setSlice(double percent, int index){
   Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
       pieChartData.get(index).setPieValue(percent);
       pieChartData.get(index).setName(caption[index]+"\n"+(int)(percent*100)+"%");
   });
}
```

3. You can also look into [Concurrency in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm) to have some knowledge on how to use [Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) and [Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html) classes

Comment: Since this seems to be an app that is integrating both JavaFX and Swing/AWT, [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm#CHDIEEJE) may also be helpful.